# .js files not being called on pages included in folders

Tags: javascript, php, mobile

At the bottom of every page, I have a .php include that links to all my .js files.

```
<?php include 'Core/js.php';?>
```

Within this .php I have this code;

```
<script src="../js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/jquery.dropotron.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/skel.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/skel-layers.min.js"> </script>
<script src="../js/init.js"></script>
<script src="../js/slider.js"></script>
```

This works perfectly for my pages placed in my root folder, ie "index.php"

However, the pages that are located in folders, don't seem to call the javascript when I use the .php include such as;

```
 <?php include '../../../Core/js.php';?>
```

Although, when I don't use the include funtion, and just paste the < script>, it calls it perfectly. This wouldn't be a huge problem for me, but it doesn't allow the mobile site to run properly.

The first pages such as "index.php" have the [mobile navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqKBf.png), whereas pages located in the folders and don't have the php include code, [don't have the same user friendly navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sj4MK.png). If someone could help me fix this, that would be great!

Comment: Could you not reference the javascript files using an absolute path rather than the relative ../../ style?

Comment: @ramraider Sorry i'm still a novice at this game. What do you mean by an absolute path?

Comment: @LewisJames An absolute path is either: `mysite.com/Core/js/js.php` or `/Core/js/js.php`. Relative paths are also a pain to manage

Comment: The term relative means that the path to the file is relative to the current location within the directory hierarchy - so as one gets deeper into the tree so the relative path must grow by adding more ../ to the path. The term absolute means that the javascript files would be stored in a root level folder ( usually ) and the path is much simpler to use ie: /js/filename.js etc

Answer (score 3):

I think your problem is about paths.

When you execute: `<script src="../js/jquery.min.js"></script>` in your browser, it looks at the URL and goes from there. Let's say you're in `http://example.com/products/index.php`. The browser will try to load the JS from `http://example.com/products/../js/jquery.min.js`, which is `http://example.com/js/jquery.min.js`.

To avoid this, you should use absolute paths, like:

```
<script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Then it will always try to load `http://example.com/js/jquery.min.js` independently from the current URL.

As for PHP includes, I would advise you to use absolute paths when including files. There are many strategies, like using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`, using `dirname()` functions, using a global variable with your includes path, etc.

Whatever you choose, your includes should look something like:

```
<?php include '/var/www/includes/Core/js.php'; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your folder structure is something like this:

```
/
    index.php
    js
       jquery.min.js
       jquery.dropotron.min.js
       skel.min.js
       ...
    Core
       js.php
    content
       some folder
          HTML files
          ...
```

So if you are inside `content` -> `some folder` -> `html file` your `js.php` should reflect this:

```
<script src="../../js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

as you could see the path changes and thats where your error comes from

Answer (score 0):

Use the absolute path. Your absolute path is the actual location on the server. An easy way to find it is look at the path you're connecting to with ftp.

It might look something like this `/home/username/public_html/Core/js.php`

Comment: Though you wouldn't use that entire path string - only the portion after /home/username/public_html in this example

Comment: I have to, but maybe it varies between server setups

Comment: Ah I see what you mean, because it's the js paths that are getting screwed up, not the php path